# how to recursively copySDcard directory and subdirectory to other smb directory(samba)?

Tags: android, smb

i am using Jcifs library.
i try this code is working copy parent directory and file but sub directory not copy..

calling function

```
for (int j = 0; j < AppConst.checkfilelist.size(); j++) {
                String old = AppConst.checkfilelist.get(j);
                Log.d("smb_c_check_item", "" + AppConst.checkfilelist.get(j));
                copyToDirectory(old, AppConst.destinationpath);

            }
```

Function

```
public int copyToDirectory(String old, String newDir) {
        try {
            SmbFile old_file = new SmbFile(old);
            SmbFile temp_dir = new SmbFile(newDir);

            Log.d("smb_c_sour:desti_dir", "" + old + "---" + newDir);

            // copy file
            if (old_file.isFile()) {

                Log.d("smb_c_file","yes");

                String file_name = old.substring(old.lastIndexOf("/"), old.length());
                Log.d("smb_c_file_name", "" + file_name);

                String servername="smb://+ ipaddress+/";


                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(servername, "", "");

                // smb file path
                SmbFile cp_smbfile = new SmbFile(newDir + file_name.substring(1),auth1);
                Log.d(" smb_c_file_path", "" + cp_smbfile);

                if (!cp_smbfile.exists())
                    cp_smbfile.createNewFile();
                cp_smbfile.connect();

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(String.valueOf((old_file)));

                SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(cp_smbfile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    sfos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                // copy directory
            } else if (old_file.isDirectory()) {

                String servername="smb://+ ipaddress+/";
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(servername, "", "");
                Log.d("smb_c_folder","yes");
                String files[] = old_file.list();

                int len = files.length;
                Log.d("smb_c_dirlength", "" + len);

                for(int i1=0;i1<len;i1++){
                    Log.d("smb_c_dir---",""+files[i1]);
                }

                // remove last character
                old = old.substring(0, old.length() - 1);
                // get dir name
                String old_f = old.substring(old.lastIndexOf("/"), old.length());
                Log.d("smb_c_old_f", "" + old_f);

                //create smbfile path
                SmbFile smbdir = new SmbFile(newDir + old_f.substring(1),auth1);


                // create new directory
                if (!smbdir.exists()) {
                    Log.d("smb_c_mkdir", "created");
                    smbdir.mkdirs();
                    //return -1;
                }

                Log.d("smb_c_dir", "" + smbdir);
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    copyToDirectory(old + "/" + files[i], smbdir + "/");
                    Log.d("smb_copy_rec", "" + old + "/" + files[i] + ":" + smbdir + "/");
                }


            } else if (!temp_dir.canWrite())
                Log.d("smb_c_dir_noperm","yes");
                return -1;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Thanx in advance for any suggestions or help.sorry for my bad eng..

Answer (score -1):

i found solution..

```
public int copySdToSmb(String old, String newDir) {
        try {

            File copyfile = new File(old);
            SmbFile temp_dir = new SmbFile(newDir);                    

            if (copyfile.isFile()) {

                SmbFile cp_smbfile = new SmbFile(newDir + copyfile.getName());                      
                if (!cp_smbfile.exists())
                    cp_smbfile.createNewFile();
                cp_smbfile.connect();
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(copyfile);
                SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(cp_smbfile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    sfos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                sfos.close();

            } else if (copyfile.isDirectory()) {
                String files[] = copyfile.list();
                // get dir name
                String old_f = old.substring(old.lastIndexOf("/"), old.length());               
                int len = files.length;
                SmbFile smbdir = new SmbFile(newDir + old_f.substring(1));

                // create new directory
                if (!smbdir.exists()) {    
                    smbdir.mkdirs();
                    //return -1;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                    copySdToSmb(old + "/" + files[i], smbdir + "/");

                }
            } else if (!temp_dir.canWrite()) {             
                return -1;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return 0;

    }
```